# Performance of Query where time captured from SP statement completed differs by large from RPC completed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, query-performance, extended-events

I am unable to understand the performance of below query when collected data from XE events:

Query

```
DECLARE @Importdate DATETIME = ISNULL ((

SELECT ImportDatetime
FROM
Customertable
where CustomerID = 1
and OrderID =1 
) , '01/01/2000')
```

This part of statement returns just 1 row

> `SP statement completed` shows **40 secs**
>
> `RPC Completed` for above statement shows **64 secs**

Need help to understand why RPC will show such a big difference and where to look for this problem ? 
I do not see any NW issue reported as such but what does this indicate here and query as simple as above seems to high for that run time

Please advice

Comment: Is this statement part of a stored procedure? RPC usually indicates a stored procedure call, which is slightly different than an ad hoc query batch. And are your times of 40 and 64 really milliseconds and not seconds?

Comment: @Solomon Rutzky - Yes, this is part of statement in stored procedure. Also yes originally time was in microseconds as collected from XE but I converted to seconds for a clarity

Comment: @Josh Darnell, Thanks , helpful, that explains why the difference in time. But however the difference is too large for my client to digest. We need to find if there is a way to save those 24 secs or reduce. How can one confirm if this is bottleneck or not and can be improved? Appreciate your response, thanks

Comment: @JoshDarnell: Sorry but i did not understand that when you say run from SSMS, my bad

Comment: @beginnerdba I posted an answer, hopefully that's more clear than my brief comments.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking [rpc_completed includes network time, while sp_statement_completed does not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244767/is-network-i-o-included-in-the-timings-for-rpc-complete-seen-in-sql-profiler).  This is very likely the case for your query, since it only returns one row.

So one explanation is the extra time is spent sending data over the network to the client.

You could try measuring wait statistics for this query to confirm there are 24 seconds of ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits that explain the difference.

If the server has SSMS installed, you could remote desktop into it and run the query there, which should have very little network wait time.  In which case you'd see very little difference in the time on those two events for this statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, you state that:

> Yes, this is part of statement in stored procedure.

Is this the only statement in the stored procedure? While not impossible if testing, it would otherwise seem odd to have a stored procedure that sets a variable and then never uses it or does anything else. So, what then of the other statements in the stored procedure? Have all of their times been accounted for?

1. `RPC:Starting` — the Remote Procedure Call to exec the proc (i.e. not an ad hoc query batch)
2. `SP:Starting` — the stored procedure starts (if it's not in the cache, time will be spent compiling it)
3. One or more sets of:

   1. `SP:StmtStarting`
   2. `SP:StmtCompleted`
4. `SP:Completed`
5. `RPC:Completed`

If you want to check for latency, be sure to capture the `EndTime` and compare the values between:

- The final `SP:StmtCompleted` and `SP:Completed`
- `SP:Completed` and `RPC:Completed`
- If there are a lot of result rows being sent back and/or the calling app isn't consuming them quickly enough, that *might* show up as a larger than expected time difference between the final `SP:StmtCompleted` and `SP:Completed`.

Otherwise:

- Compile time *might* be difference between `EndTime` of `SP:Starting` and `StartTime` of first `SP:StmtStarting`.
- What other statements are in this proc and what are there durations?

Next, are we *really* talking about seconds here? 40 seconds for a `SELECT` of a single column given two `INT` (or similar) predicates? Even without an index to help I would expect such a query to return well before 40 seconds, unless there's *a lot* of contention and/or the table has billions of rows, or something like that. Is it possible that you divided by the wrong number? I think you're supposed to divide by `1000000`. If these numbers are correct, then I would be more concerned about why that simple `SELECT` is taking 40 seconds than I would be about whatever else is taking up the remaining 24 seconds.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Yes i calculated correctly as originally from XE its microseconds so converted to seconds. Even that is what we are figuring out why it will go that slow, table is 200 M rows, not billion and no contention at server level. Its got good resources