# extended events rpc_completed duration does not matching with rpc_starting

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

[image]Does rpc_completed duration (micro_sec) = rpc_starting.timestamp - rpc_completed.timestamp?
In my case, I saw a big difference between them. Duration is only few millsec, where rpc_starting.timestamp - rpc_completed.timestamp is 6 - 10 sec.
[image]

I am on enterprise 2016 sp2-cu14, the duration field is in microsecond. I did similar thing for catching sp_statement_starting and sp_statement_completed, sp_batch_starting/sp_batch_completed inside rpc_starting and rpc_completed. it shows the same situation. My question is "which one tell me how much time the query actually took? Is it Duration in sp_statement_completed or the difference between starting and completed?"

Comment: What version of SQL Server, and what tool are you using to examine the events?

Comment: The duration should be accurate.  Can you test with SSMS to see which one is correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe the duration column represents the difference in time of the timestamp_UTC column between the `rpc_starting` and `rpc_completed` events. Assuming you're on any version of SQL Server still relevant (2008 R2+) that column is in units of microseconds (anything older version and it's in milliseconds), and therefore is a very small value in your examples (e.g. 1,872 microseconds = 0.00187 seconds).

My guess based on [Microsoft's description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/rpc-completed-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15) is that is literally how long it took that particular event to occur and be recorded.

Comment: I am on enterprise 2016 sp2-cu14, the duration field is in microsecond. I did similar thing for catching sp_statement_starting and sp_statement_completed, sp_batch_starting/sp_batch_completed inside rpc_starting and rpc_completed. it shows the same situation. My question is "which one tell me how much time the query actually took? Is it Duration in sp_statement_completed or the difference between starting and completed?"

Comment: From my understanding in the doc, it's the difference between the StartTime and EndTime field.

Comment: It is strange that many people only use duration in *_completed instead of difference between start and completed to determining long running queries. (e.g. duration>1000000 for more than 1 sec). In my case the duration is so short compare to start and completed.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is "which one tell me how much time the query actually took? Is it Duration in sp_statement_completed or the difference between starting and completed?"

"Duration" in the `sp_statement_completed` event is how long the query actually took at the server.  It doesn't include the time spent sending results to the client (usually, see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244767/is-network-i-o-included-in-the-timings-for-rpc-complete-seen-in-sql-profiler) for details).

I'm not 100% sure why the Extended Events timestamp column shows such a large discrepancy between the "starting" and "completed" events, but that's not where you want to focus your attention.